# Count occurrences found in GridView of word entered in TextBox

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2012

I have a textbox filter search and I want a button to count the number of textbox_search words that are found in grideview and display the total in a label on a form.

```
Dim d1 As New DataTable
```

### This is the Search

```
Dim dv As New DataView(d1)
dv.RowFilter = String.Format("   Name  like '%{0}%'", TextBox1.Text)

DataGridView1.DataSource = dv
```

Comment: Please try to explain better what you want, the way you did it, it is not very clear what you are asking for.

Comment: yes, when i search about any company_name will apear all data in gridview , i wont to know the number of all company_name that i search of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count the number of rows returned after filtering the `DataView`, using the `DataView.RowFilter` property, you could use [`DataView.Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.count) property or [`DataGridView.Rows.Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.count) property, like this:

```vb
Dim d1 As New DataTable
Dim dv As New DataView(d1)
' Using interpolated string to set up the filter.
dv.RowFilter = $"Name LIKE '%{TextBox1.Text}%'"

DataGridView1.DataSource = dv

CountByDvLabel.Text = dv.Count.ToString()
CountByDgvLabel.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString()
```

Comment: thanck you for reply

Comment: library, the best way to thank for an answer is to mark it as accepted by clicking on the check mark (✓). But do so only if some response has answered your original question. When you reach 15 reputation points you can also [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) for an answer or question. See: [Someone answered me](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why vote?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). Also make the [tour] for an initial explanation of how the site works.

Comment: Does my response answer your original question?